# String to Wstring C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, wstring

How to convert String to a WString.

Before can convert the EscapeXML I need to convert first the string to wstring.

Example:

I have a string value = "& & &", then I want to convert this string to wstring.

**My Source-Code:**

```
string escapeXML(const std::string & value)
{
   // Here
   CA2W ca2w(value.c_str());
   wstring value = ca2w;

    int output_size = EscapeXML(value.c_str(), value.length(), 0, 0, ATL_ESC_FLAG_ATTR);

    std::wstring testout;
    testout.resize(output_size);
    EscapeXML(value.c_str(), value.length(), &testout[0], output_size, ATL_ESC_FLAG_ATTR);

    using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

    string converted_str = converter.to_bytes(testout);

    return converted_str;
}

int main()
{

std::string test =  " & & & ";
cout << escapeXML(test) << '/n';

    return 0;
}
```

**My Output:**

```
C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'value'
IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"
```

Comment: Without running your code, I can't see your problem/question?  What were you expecting, what did you get/see?

Comment: I update now the case. I hope you can understand the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice @computerfreaker.

Answer (score 0):

I found now the problem. The Problem is about the duplication of values.

I have in string called value and in wstring called value. This way shouldn't work. I change the valuename, that's the solution. Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlenc.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;


string escapeXML(const std::string & value)
{
    CA2W ca2w(value.c_str());
    wstring value2 = ca2w;
    int output_size = EscapeXML(value2.c_str(), value.length(), 0, 0, ATL_ESC_FLAG_ATTR);

    std::wstring testout;
    testout.resize(output_size);
    EscapeXML(value2.c_str(), value2.length(), &testout[0], output_size, ATL_ESC_FLAG_ATTR);

    using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

    string converted_str = converter.to_bytes(testout);

    return converted_str;
}



int main()
{

    std::string test =  " Bayern & Münschen";
    std::string test2 = " \" \" \" ";
    std::string test3 = " ' ' ' ";
    std::string test4 = "< < <";
    std::string test5 = " > > >";

    cout << escapeXML(test);
    cout << escapeXML(test2) << '/n';
    cout << escapeXML(test3) << '/n';
    cout << escapeXML(test4) << '/n';
    cout << escapeXML(test5) << '/n';

    return 0;
}
```